# Issue with NumberPrompt<> in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I've added the following dialog to my waterfall :

```
AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>($"{nameof(ValidationDialog)}.integer"));
```

It is prompted in the following function :

```
 private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CheckNumeric(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(ValidationDialog)}.integer",
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter an integer number greater than 0 or press any letter to skip"),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Invalid number, try again!")
            }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

**Input:** 3*10^2

**Expected Output:** The prompt should **accept the input** or re-prompt and return **Invalid number, try again!**

**Actual Output:** It stores only 3 as the input.

Comment: the above behavior is because the NumberRecognizer.RecognizeNumber  recognizes the input as a number and parses 3*10^2 as 3 to be the value(which is >0). What you can do is add a validator that checks if the value recognized is same as the value the user entered. You can refer to the [multi-turn](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt) prompt sample which has a number prompt with validation.